# How to disable high lighting with CSS?

Tags: css, frontend

I am trying to disable highlighting with CSS. It is pretty easy for a user to accidentally highlight elements on my site, and it ruins the appearance. What CSS property can I use to stop this?

highlight example:
[image]

Comment: Show us the code that you tried so far.

Comment: I tried using :focus{ outline: none; }

Comment: You have to show some snippet or fiddle so someone can help more accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out.

```
.noselection {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
  -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  supported by Chrome and Opera */
}
```